# How to delete images in a collection view?

Tags: kotlin, collectionview

Since I'm trying to show a collection of images as a preview, I'm using this library from Github:

https://github.com/AgnaldoNP/PreviewImageCollection

This is the XML code in my app:

```
<pereira.agnaldo.previewimgcol.ImageCollectionView
                android:id="@+id/imageCollectionView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                />
```

I point to ImageCollectionView using this code:

```
collectionView = findViewById(R.id.imageCollectionView)
```

To this collection view, I add bitmaps with a for loop using the method collectionView.addImage(bitmap).
Everything works fine, but I can't figure out how to remove the images once added. I've tried using the method collectionView.removeAllViews(). It does make the images disappear, however, once I add new images to the collection view, the previous images are still there.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to use Flexbox layout (https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout) or StaggeredGridLayout with RecyclerView

Comment: What is the best way if I want to show images as a mosaic like in facebook?

Comment: If you want like instagram search page, then it has a pattern if you noticed, one big square image of 2 rows size and in right of that 2 images and below down that big image shifts to left and those 2 images to left and soon pattern

Comment: There they are using only pattern or you can say a custom staggered grid recyclerview